# Select min, max year in table and define the rest

Tags: mysql, select, range, max, min

I have to select min and max year of a column and define the remaining years. Can this be done using sql query itself. I do not wish to use php code(this would be last option)

```
 Give the range from (select min(Tax filing), max(Tax filing) from tax);

 //Simply writing "Define the range from(nested query)".. please give some query tags which apply..
```

[image]

So it should define the range automatically. Can that be done using any query?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean define the rest?

Answer (score 2):

```
select somegunk from sometable    
   where somedate between 
       (select max(year(someotherdate)) from sometable) 
   and (select min(year(someotherdate)) from sometable);
```

Comment: some explanation might help here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all the years between the min and max year then the following should do it :

```
SELECT yearCol
 from yourTable
 where yearCol between
   (select min(yearCol) from yourTable)
 and
  (select max(yearCol)FROM yourTable);
```

you need to have records for all the years in between in yourTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence table where you insert all the possible values:

```
create table sequence (id integer not null auto_increment primary key) auto_increment=1900;

insert into  sequence values(null); -- x times
```

and use this query:

```
select * from sequence where id between (select min(Tax_filing) from tax) and (select max(Tax_filing) from tax);
```